# Count number of hours between 2 dates excluding weekends and between 10pm - 10am?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to calculate the number of hours between two date/times, excluding bank holidays and between 10pm and 10am.

I've got the Start Datetime in B3, and then End Datetime in G3. In SLA B13 - B22, I have a list of the bank holiday dates for 2015, and I am using the following forumal

```
=SUM(G3-B3-COUNTIFS(SLA!B13:B22,">"&B3,SLA!B13:B22,"<"&G3))
```

For some reason, I cant get this to exclude bank holidays, however I then also nee to take into account the 10pm - 10am bracket.

Can anyone help?

Comment: An appropriate answer will depend on how accurate you want to be. You mentioned **date/times** yet provided no samples with expected results.

Answer (score 1):

```
=NETWORKDAYS(B3;G3;SLA!B13:B22)*12
```

*12 because only 12 hours per day count (exclude time between 10 pm and 10 am)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your formula and it works fine for whole days for me, as long as you format the cell containing the formula as general or number to avoid formatting it as a date. It doesn't exclude weekends of course which presumably is what you want.

You might want to add 1 to make it inclusive, make > into >= and < into <= in case the start and end dates are bank holidays and multiply by 12 to get the result in hours:-

```
=(G3-B3+1-COUNTIFS(SLA!B13:B22,">="&B3,SLA!B13:B22,"<="&G3))*12
```

You could calculate the hours worked directly from datetime values: the basic formula would be:-

```
=(G3-B3)*24-(INT(G3)-INT(B3))*12
```

i.e. subtracting 12 hours for each complete day.

You could also exclude the holidays (if between the start and end dates):-

```
=(G3-B3)*24-(INT(G3)-INT(B3)+COUNTIFS(SLA!B13:B22,">"&B3,SLA!B13:B22,"<"&G3))*12
```

i.e. subtracting a further 12 hours for each day's holiday.

One more thing you could do is to apply an adjustment for start and end time to the Networkdays formula by adding:-

```
=MOD(G3,1)-MOD(B3,1)
```